# JS returning a value gives "undefined"

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, electron

i'm currently working with electron and I need to get some data from a mysql database, what is working good.

But there is a problem with sending values between functions. I'm kinda new to JS and electron, so maybe i just missed something:

```
function getUserData(user, data){

// connect
var connection = connect();

// Perform a query
$query = 'SELECT ' + data + ' FROM `users` WHERE user_id = ' + user;

// Query ausführen
connection.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err){
        console.log("There was an error with executing the query.");
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    return rows;
});

// End function
return;
}
```

So basically i want to return "rows", but it says it's undefined.
Right above

```
return rows;
```

if i check with

```
console.log(rows);
```

it has data in it

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You return undefined from your function.  Also I am not familiar with that api but you probably want to return connection.query(.....).  Latestly, that function is vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you actually return undefined with `return;`.

If it (`connection.query`) is synchronous then just do `return connection.query(/*smth*/)`.
If it is asynchronous you won't be able to do that this easily and the best you can do is, in the function provided as argument, change the value of a variable that is globally defined (or return the Promise/"asynchronous handling" object if there's one).